# xslt what is being selected here <xsl:for-each select="./child::*">

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few questions please.

What is the `*` for in this statement?

```
count(*[substring(@Title,4,1) = '_'])
```

What does the period do?

```
count(./tcm:Page[starts-with(@Title, '000_')])
```

What does the `./child::*` look for?

```
<xsl:for-each select="./child::*">
```

What does the `::` mean and do?

```
count(./child::tcm:Page[starts-with(@Title, '000_')])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all pretty basic XPath questions.

> What is the * for in this statement?

It stands for *any element*.

> What does the period do?

In this case, nothing. A location step of `.` is short for `self::node()`. But you are already there, so instead of:

```
count(./tcm:Page[starts-with(@Title, '000_')])
```

you can write:

```
count(tcm:Page[starts-with(@Title, '000_')])
```

> What does the ./child::* look for?

It looks for any element that is a child of the current node. As before, it can be shortened to just `*`, because (1) `.` does not move you anywhere, and (2) child is the default axis.

> What does the :: mean and do

From the XPath specification:

> The syntax for a location step is the axis name and node test
>   **separated by a double colon**, followed by zero or more expressions each
>   in square brackets.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Location-Steps